# Getting server information with only FTP access

Tags: linux, ftp, backup

I'm in the process of re-installing a backup of a PHP script on a new server.

The previous web developer has gone missing in action and he has yet to release the domain in that's under his management.

So for the new server they only provided me with mySQL details and FTP access. They say they don't have temporary testing url so I can only upload the backup without testing it.

I changed the mySQL server variables but in the script there are also some server side specifics. For example the full path has to be defined in the config file. I only have FTP access so I can't run a simple phpinfo().

Is there any other way to get this specific server information with only FTP access? I basically need the full server path where the script will be installed.

Thanks!

Comment: uh, if you've got ftp access, then you can upload files, which means you can upload a script to a web directory which contains the phpinfo() call...

Comment: @Marc B Incorrect. I have ftp access to an IP address (new server). The actual domain (FQDN) is still pending and connected to a previous server. The account where I login is just an IP address from a server and the account information redirects me to a specific folder on that server. I don't know the http equivalent of that ftp folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, IF apache (or whichever webserver) on that IP is already configured for your FQDN (which you couldn't set to the new IP yet), then you could upload a PHP file with a phpinfo() call. Afterwards you could telnet onto the known IP port 80 and send

```
GET /[PHP-File] HTTP/1.1
Host: [Your FQDN]
```

So e.g., if your FQDN was www.example.com:

```
GET /info.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

The web server should then send the output of your PHP script.

Note that your lines have to end with a `<CR><LF>` and that there is a blank line after your Host:-line.

Comment: Hi Philipp, I only have access to the FTP using an IP address . The actual FQDN is still pointing  to the old server (old IP). I don't have any http link to actually test the files, only FTP access using an IP and authentication.

Comment: Yes. This was the information on how to access the HTTP-Server even without having a link to type into your browser, given the Webserver is configured properly. The FQDN does not need to point to the new IP for that. `Host: www.example.com` is part of the HTTP specification. This way you can tell the web server (by connecting to its IP) which domain you would like to have returned, even if the domain doesen't point there by DNS yet.